# CString : What does (TCHAR*)(this + 1) mean?

Tags: mfc, c-strings, ofc

In the CString header file (be it Microsoft's or Open Foundation Classes - http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid035C2F57DD64DBF54840B7C00EA7105DFDAA0EBD.aspx#L77 ), there is the following code snippet

```
struct CStringData
{   
    long nRefs;
    int nDataLength;
    int nAllocLength;
    TCHAR* data() { return (TCHAR*)(&this[1]); };
    ...
};
```

What does the **(TCHAR*)(&this[1])** indicate?

The CStringData struct is used in the CString class (http :// www.koders.com/cpp/fid100CC41B9D5E1056ED98FA36228968320362C4C1.aspx).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CString has lots of internal tricks which make it look like a normal string when passed e.g. to `printf` functions, despite actually being a class - **without having to cast it to `LPCTSTR` in the argument list, e.g., in the case of `varargs` (`...`) in e.g. a `printf`**. Thus trying to understand a single individual trick or function in the CString implementation is bad news. (The data function is an internal function which gets the 'real' buffer associated with the string.)

There's a book, MFC Internals that goes into it, and IIRC the Blaszczak book might touch it.

EDIT: As for what the expression actually translates to in terms of raw C++:-

```
TCHAR* data() { return (TCHAR*)(&this[1]); };
```

this says "pretend you're actually the first entry in an array of items allocated together. Now, the second item isnt actually a `CString`, it's a normal NUL terminated buffer of either Unicode or normal characters - i.e., an LPTSTR".

Another way of expressing the same thing is:

```
TCHAR* data() { return (TCHAR*)(this + 1); };
```

When you add 1 to a pointer to T, you actually add 1* sizeof T in terms of a raw memory address. So if one has a CString located at 0x00000010 with sizeof(CString) = 4, data will return a pointer to a NUL terminated array of chars buffer starting at 0x00000014

But just understanding this one thing out of context isnt necessarily a good idea.

Why do you *need* to know?

Comment: This doesn't refer to MFC, but to OFC.

Comment: @kgiannakakis: Didnt follow links or read question, doh. However the reasons are likely to be the same

Comment: @Ruben: Thanks for that. I think I figured it out based on your reply and kgiannakakis's reply.
The (this + 1) basically points to the offset into the CString type where the actual content can be found. The mem_alloc statement makes it clearer. 
This was just a learning exercise. Hence the question.

Comment: Great, ta for 't accept. I +1'd kgiannakakis (for prodding me into improving my answer beyond it's initial state in addition to it being a valid answer that helps you understand what's going on) and you should too IMNSHO :D

Answer (score 1):

It returns the memory area that is immediately after the CStringData structure as an array of TCHAR characters.

You can  understand why they are doing this if you look at the [CString.cpp](http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid100CC41B9D5E1056ED98FA36228968320362C4C1.aspx?s=CStringData) file:

```
static const struct {
    CStringData data;
    TCHAR ch;
} str_empty = {{-1, 0, 0}, 0};

CStringData* pData = (CStringData*)mem_alloc(sizeof(CStringData) + size*sizeof(TCHAR));
```

Comment: @kgiannakakis: Didnt Looks like a reimpl of MFC's CString, so the reasons why they did it (to make one be able to pass the CString to a `...` in a printf without an explicit cast) stands.

Answer (score 0):

They do this trick, so that CString looks like a normal data buffer, and when you ask for the getdata it skips the CStringData structure and  points directly to the  real data buffer like char*